# InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() returns 127.0.0.1 in Android

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming

My application uses multicast to send a beacon in periods along with protocol message and ip of the host joining the multicast group. In android device it is returning 127.0.0.1. I have looked around and found that many people suggested changing a host file. But, in case of android it is not possible in my context. How do I get real IP of the device, not the loopback address..

```
private void getLocalAddress()
{
    try {
        String localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        servers.add(localHost);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: On my phone, unless it's have Wi-Fi activated and are connected to a Wi-Fi network, it doesn't have an IP-address. If there is no local address then `getLocalHost` returns the loopback address, which is what you get.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg try my answer.I hope this will solve ur problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Modified few bits and this one is working as desired for getting IPv4 addresses. !inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() removes all the loopback address. !inetAddress.isLinkLocalAddress() and inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) removes all IPv6 addresses. I hope this will help someone in here.

```
    StringBuilder IFCONFIG=new StringBuilder();
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && !inetAddress.isLinkLocalAddress() && inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                IFCONFIG.append(inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString()+"\n");
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", ex.toString());
    }
    servers.add(IFCONFIG.toString());
```

Comment: Just to make sure no one forget about it, you'll need INTERNET permission on your AndroidManifest.xml:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Why do you use `\n` here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
String hostname = args[0];
try 
    {
      InetAddress ipaddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
      System.out.println("IP address: " + ipaddress.getHostAddress());
    }
    catch ( UnknownHostException e )
    {
      System.out.println("Could not find IP address for: " + hostname);
    }
```

Comment: when my application is shipped..how do you think will it be possible to provide hostname for all users using the app? Do you know any other way to find it?

Answer (score 0):

From my tries, the maximum I could get was the wifi network address.

I don't know any other way rather than actually calling a webserver that returns the ip address. Obviously, the problem with this is that it uses the phone data.