# How to show what is my URL address (HttpPost) in logcat?

Tags: android, http-post, tostring, logcat

I have a login screen that when user clicks on login button, i need to add some information to URL address. This is my code for past data:

```
private String postData() {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PropertyManager.getLoginURL());

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u", Uri.encode(PropertyManager.getUserId())));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p", Encryption.encrypt(PropertyManager.getPassword())));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("v", PropertyManager.VER));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("t", "0"));

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.i("Server Response 1: ", responseBody);
        if (response.containsHeader("Set-Cookie")) {
                PropertyManager.setSessionID(extractSessionId(response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie")[0].getValue()));
        }
        return responseBody;
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException usee) {
        usee.printStackTrace();
    } catch(ClientProtocolException cpe) {
        cpe.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return null;
}
```

Actually this method is working fine when my device is connected to Internet through WiFi and 3G. But just for one device (Sony Ericson - Xperia) when it is connected to 3G (WiFi is ok) server sends nonsense response.

I need to see my connection address with its detail parameter. I wrote this code:

```
Log.i("Requestd Connection", httppost.getURI().toString());
```

However, I could see just my URL without any nameValuePairs parameters.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: try with Log.i("Requestd Connection",httpPost.getEntity().toString());

Comment: Try looking here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128019/inetaddress-getlocalhost-gethostaddress-returns-127-0-0-1-in-android

Comment: @ M Mohsin Naeem, Thanks for your suggestion but the in log cat it shows: org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity@2c1be020  which is not the thing that i'm looking for.

Comment: @ Quintin Balsdon: I didn't find it related to my question.